# How to use DllImport with interfaces in C#?

Tags: c#, interface, dllimport

I have several `DllImport`s with respect to `user32.dll` in my code and I thought them to be declared in an interface. But that gives me errors saying `public`, `static`, `extern` are not valid with each item.

Example interface code is as follows:

```
public interface IWindowsFunctions
{
   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
   static extern int MessageBox(int hWnd, string msg, string title, uint flags);
}
```

Is there any specific way of using this in an interface, or is there an alternative or is it impossible with an interface?

Thanks

Comment: The other answers already explain it's impossible to place these definitions in an interface. But my questions is why you want to do this in an interface in the first place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well its already been mentioned many times now that a DLLImport is an implementation, and therefore cannot be defined on an interface, but I thought it would still be worth mentioning that normally I group by DLLImports into a "NativeMethods" class for organisation, like so:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int MessageBox(int hWnd, string msg, string title, uint flags);
}
```

Example use:

```
NativeMethods.MessageBox(myWnd, "Hello World", "Hello", flags);
```

Comment: +1 for using the recommended guidelines (NativeMethods as classname and internal as accessor)

Comment: @Claus Jørgensen: Looks like I'm gonna have to refactor my code. Where are these guidelines by the way?

Comment: @BoltClock: StyleCop pitches a huge fit if you don't put all your interop code in a class called `NativeMethods`. Microsoft therefore does it for their own code, and it's become a guideline.

Comment: @Cody Gray: So I've in fact been doing it wrong (well, close enough...) :)

Comment: @BoltClock: Not really. It doesn't make much practical difference unless you use StyleCop or apply the `SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute`. But it's become so commonly accepted that other developers will probably have an easier time finding your P/Invoke defs if they're in a such-named class. This is one of those "conventions" that I sometimes think has gotten out of hand, and in a few years, we'll see people backlashing against it. (Hungarian, anyone?)

Comment: Its a good guideline - far better than scattering PInvoke declarations in every other class.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Well, alright. I'll leave my answer as is for anyone to view history or rollback if they're so inclined to see how I did it. In the meantime I'm itching to refactor my code now.

Comment: @Kragen: Just to be clear, I agree it's *always* a good idea to place interop code in a single class declared as `internal`/`Friend`. The point was just that StyleCop is the only thing that cares if you call it `NativeMethods`. I named mine `Win32Interop` or `NativeInterop` for the longest time before I "knew better".

Comment: Yes, and by refactor I mean separate managed calls from unmanaged extern calls, placing the latter in said internal class. Thanks again, guys.

Comment: And how are you going to test this now if you spill your code with references to a static class all over the place ? That is against IOC

Answer (score 4):

It's already implemented - the implementation is found in `user32.dll`. That's what the [`extern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5.aspx) keyword means:

> The **extern** modifier is used to declare a method that is implemented externally.

Interfaces can only declare instance methods for their implementors; as such the `static` keyword is not valid here either.

Lastly, an interface can't declare implementations; only its implementors can. In this case, since the implementation already exists, it makes no sense to create an interface for it.

If you're looking to create a wrapper class for unmanaged calls, see [Kragen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548401/how-to-use-dllimport-with-interfaces-in-c/5548632#5548632).

Answer (score 1):

Interface methods cannot have accessibility modifiers, meaning you can't apply any  static/extern/public/private/etc decorators to them.

I don't see why you'd want to use an interface for this; it's non-standard and by convention a `DllImport` method is implementation, which does not belong in an interface.

Instead you can use a static class, or even a struct.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. A DllImport is about *implementation*, and an interface says nothing about implementation. Also, C# does not have the concept of static interfasces.

You can create an interface with the correct signature, and create a class that implements that interface, if you want.

Comment: You cannot "create an interface with the correct signature, and create a class that implements that interface, if you want" because a method marked DllImport must be static and extern and a method implementing an interface cannot be static.